# A generalization of the implicit function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

$F $ is a smooth function:$\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ ,such that:

(i)$F(0,0)=0$
(ii)$\exists k_1,k_2\ge0,$ such that $\partial^{k_1}_x\partial^{k_2}_yF(0,0) \ne 0 $
Now we want to know whether $F^{-1}(0)$ around $(0,0)$ is included by a union of images of finite $C^1$ functions?These functions can be $y=f(x)$ or $x = g(y)$.
This may be a generalization of the implicit function theorem.I don't know whether it's correct.Can you give a proof or a counter example?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "...included by a union of images..." but you wouldn't get a generalization of the Implicit Function Theorem.
Consider $F(x,y):=x^2+y^2$ on $\mathbb R^2$. Then $F(0,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial x^2}(0,0)=\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y^2}(0,0)=2$ but $F^{-1}(0)=\{(0,0)\}$.